# Redis design for a queue system

Tags: redis

I am currently building a sort of a queue system but I have a few questions designing the system with Redis.

Basically I will have many shops and in each shop, there will be many users.

I would like to record the profile of the user, such as handphone number, queue number, email, timeofqueue.

The queue number has to be in order. The users' queue numbers are also updated when a user in the middle leaves the queue. (meaning when user of queue number 2 leaves, the other users having queue number 3 4 5 6 7, becomes 2 3 4 5 6.

My data would be like this for the shops:

```
shop1 : {
    user1: {
        handphone: 4520502124,
        name: "david",
        time: "11.50AM"
    },
    user2: {
        handphone: 4501250125,
        name: "peter",
        time: "12.00PM"
    },
    user3: {
        handphone: 401201250,
        name: "john",
        time: "12.15PM"
    }
}

shop2 : {
    user1: {
        handphone: 12561256126,
        name: "andy",
        time: "12.00PM"
    }
    user2: {
        handphone: 512561261,
        name: "belle",
        time: "01.00PM"
    }



shop1queue: ["user1","user2","user3"];
shop2queue: ["user1","user2"];
```

I use hashes to store the users' profiles and i probably can remove them by HDEL.
I use sorted sets to hold the queue numbers, and whenever a user in the middle leaves, I can use ZRANK to get the queue number of the other users.

Question:

**For my scenario, is using sorted sets for holding the queue numbers the right approach?**

**If I would like to get all the hash keys in shop1 including the values inside, how do I do that in Redis?**

Answer (score 2):

Storing the users' details in hashes is a good idea. Then in the sorted set you can use the `id` of the user as the member, and the `timestamp` as the score. That way, the rank is calculated automatically even if you eliminate some member.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the timestamp, however i would like to also get the values of all the hashes in shop1 specifically, how do it do that?

Comment: For this you should run some benchmarks to see if the process is fast enough for the amount of data you have. One solution is to first fetch the ids, then pipeline many `HMGET` commands. The other idea is to create a lua script that collects all the `HMGET` and returns a multibulk with that information. If you have too many items, the performance will degrade and you will have to find other solution (for example, you will have to query ranges instead of all the data at once).

Comment: Nice, I went to look at Lua scripting and its powerful. This is where i learn to get the multibulk reply, http://www.redisgreen.net/library/smemhashes.html. Sorry i couldn't upvote your answer i aint have enough rep yet :/ Thanks for the tips though!